# How to Compare 2 excel sheet row wise where order of data is not fixed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Comparing 2 excel sheets where we need to find id and match next column and if difference then highlight the difference cell.
eg;

```
 Sheet 1
 123412 Bob   Y
 112234 Jill  Y
 998822 Carry Blank

 Sheet 2
 112234 Jill  XX
 998822 Carry Blank
 123412 Jack  ZZ
```

Here sheet 2, 123412 has different data in col2 and col4
Also, Sheet 2, 112234 has different data in Col3 when compared with sheet1
I need to highlight the cells so that difference can be identified easily.
There is huge amount of data.

Highlight, Sheet2- Jack, ZZ and XX cells and
Sheet1 - Bob, Y, Y(of Jill)

Comment: There's not a single field that has the same data across the two samples you gave.  None of the columns match up.  Why are you suggesting that only col2 and col4 don't match?  Also, what output do you actually want from the provided data?

Comment: row 1 of sheet1 should search and find row 3 of sheet2 as 1st column is same then search column wise comparing both sheets eg; sheet1.A1 = sheet2.A1 this matches hence is true then check sheet1.B1 i.e its next column with sheet2.YY i.e sheet2.A1's next column, then this do not match hence highlight it or get the difference. similarly go on checking with next column i.e sheet1.C1 with sheet2.C1 again matches so do not highlight go to next column i.e sheet1.D1 compare with sheet2.ZZ do not match so highlight. Next time compare 2nd row similarly the 3rd and so on...Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Part of the confusion is that you are using strings that are also cell names.  `Sheet2!A1` contains the string "A2", which makes it very hard to discuss what we're looking at, since "A2" could also refer to a cell directly.  `Sheet2!A1` does not contain the same string as `Sheet1!A1`, so I can't figure out why you say "sheet1.A1 = sheet2.A1" when the cells pretty obviously contain different strings.

Comment: Here I am talking about string names not cell name. Also tried this let me change the value =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!A1:E2254,2,0)),"Removed",IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!A1:E2254,2,0)=B2,VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!A1:E2254,2,0)=C2, VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!A1:E2254,2,0)=D2,VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!A1:E2254,2,0)=E2),"Same","Changed to: " &VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!A1:E2254,2,0)))